# Apply Consumer many times at once using standard library

Tags: java

Are there any ways to use consumer in chain without writing code or adding additional libraries?
Now it's like:

```
Consumer s = str -> System.out.println(str);
s.accept("abc");
s.accept("fgh");
s.accept("xyz");
```

Is there a way to turn it into something like

```
Consumer s = str -> System.out.println("str");
s.accept("abc").accept("fgh").accept("xyz")
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned `Consumer` returns `void` so you can't chain them. But everything comes down to how complex is the thing you are trying to achieve. For instance your particular example could have been written in such way:

```
Stream.of("abc", "fgh", "xyz").forEach(System.out::println);
```

Strings can be replace with any object and the `Consumer` can be of any complexity. However if you don't need to execute consumer on every value in one chain then this approach won't fit you.

Answer (score 3):

Because `accept()` returns [`void`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#accept-T-), what you ask is not possible "out of the box".
But, you could probably create some *wrapper* to do what you want. For example:

```
class ChainedConsumer<T> { 

    private final Consumer<T> consumer;

    public ChainedConsumer(final Consumer<T> consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    public ChainedConsumer<T> accept(final T s) {
        this.consumer.accept(s);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that accept won't help. But maybe there is some standard way for what I want that maps consumer into function that applies consumer and return itself?

Answer (score 1):

if your environment allows to make a wrapper of `Consumer` you will be able to create your own `accept` method, changing signature from `void` to `Consumer` and return `this` always as in the builder pattern.